# About JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script>
function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>


<script>
function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = displayDate();
}
</script>
```

Why program executed when I write `Date();` and not executed writing `displayDate();`?

Is there reason for this?

Comment: [Are you serious?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237671/about-javascript-events#comment56217993_34237671)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because second one is recursive with no terminate condition.

Answer (score 0):

`displayDate()` is a function that's only applicable in some cases - like calendar or datepicker in some browsers.

`Date()` is a built-in JS object that can be printed used for innerHTML. But you should probably do `Date.getDate()`.